# Excel 2013 Open a file and prompt user with "Author would like you to open as read-only"

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an excel file. When the file is opened I would like the user to be prompted with the message "The author would like you to open file_abc.xlsm as read-only unless you need to make changes. Open as read-only?"

For the life of me I can't find the box to tick. What's even worse is I did this about two weeks ago from some of my other workbooks. Can someone please tell me where the option is located in Excel 2013?

Thanks!

Comment: Google 'excel 2013 recommended read only' and click the first few links will answer this **user** question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While saving the excel file (or 'Save As' for already saved files) when the Browse window appears asking file name, type, location etc :  there is a 'tools' dropdown select just at the left of the save button. Click on it and select: 'General Options'. A mini option window appears with 'Backup Creation' / 'Password Protection' and a check box called '**Read Only Recommended**'. Check that option and save your file. Thats all.

How is it related to any programming, by the way?